# C: How to add structs to pointer array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Kind of new to C, and i ve looked all over to solve this but i haven t been able to find anything.
Okay so i have these structs:

```
typedef struct pixel_lab {
  double L; // Lightness channel
  double a; // Magenta/Green channel
  double b; // Cyan/Yellow channel
} Color_lab;

#define MAX_DIM 3
struct kd_node
{
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    Color_lab *pix;
    struct kd_node *father;
    struct kd_node *left;
    struct kd_node *right;

} kd_node;

typedef struct kd_node Kd_node;
```

And this function that will be recursive:

```
void function (Color_lab *pixels, int k, Kd_node* pater, int finish, int start){
 if (k>0){
    int size;
    size = floor(finish-start)/2 + 1;

    Color_lab* pixels_1[size];

    int cont1=0;
    for (int x = start; x < finish; x++){
        *pixels_1[cont1] = pixels[x];
        cont1++;
    }
    function(pixels_1 , k-1, pater, finish/2, start);
 }
```

Where pixels is a Color_lab array.

So i want to have an array of Color_labs (subset of the original ones) that i can reinsert in the function. For this obviously i need it to be the same type, but no matter how I put it, I get a segmentation error or incompatible types (actually this piece of code is just one that doesn t give me incompatible types, but I ve moved the pointer just about everywhere).

I m trying to assign the current pixel directly to the new array but seemingly that s not how it works, any help?

Thanks!

*Edit

Here s the whole code with the changes I was told (and pix forom the struct above is no longer a pointer). The part that s failing (adding the array), although I put in the base condition. This piece s only attempt is to run the rest of the code in the function with only part of the original Color_lab array. I know the problem isn t when it starts recursing, because I m trying the code without it and I narrowed it down to the array.

```
 void palletear (Color_lab *pixels, int k, Kd_node* pater, int inicio, int fin, int first, int side){

  if (k > 0){
    double gmrangemin = 255;
    double byrangemin = 255;
    double lumrangemin = 255;
    double gmrangemax = 0;
    double byrangemax = 0;
    double lumrangemax = 0;

    double lum[fin - inicio];
    double gm[fin - inicio];
    double by[fin - inicio];

    int size;
    size = fin - inicio + 1;

    Color_lab pixeles_lado1[size];
    Color_lab pixeles_lado2[size];

    for (int x = inicio; x < fin; x++){
        if (lumrangemin > pixels[x].L){
          lumrangemin = pixels[x].L;
        }
        else if (lumrangemax< pixels[x].L){
          lumrangemax = pixels[x].L;  
        }
        if (gmrangemin > pixels[x].a){
          gmrangemin = pixels[x].a;
        }
        else if (gmrangemax< pixels[x].a){
          gmrangemax = pixels[x].a;  
        }
        if (byrangemin > pixels[x].b){
          byrangemin = pixels[x].b;
        }
        else if (byrangemax< pixels[x].b){
          byrangemax = pixels[x].b;  
        }
        lum[x] = pixels[x].L;
        gm[x] = pixels[x].a;
        by[x] = pixels[x].b;
    };

    if ((lumrangemax - lumrangemin) >= (gmrangemax - gmrangemin)){
      quickSort(lum, 0, sizeof(lum)/sizeof(lum[0])-1);
      double median;
      if ((sizeof(lum)/sizeof(lum[0]))%2 == 0) {
        median = ((lum[(sizeof(lum)/sizeof(lum[0]))/2]) + ((lum[(sizeof(lum)/sizeof(lum[0]))/2]) + 1))/2;
      }
      else{
        median = lum[((sizeof(lum)/sizeof(lum[0])) + 1)/2];
      }
      printf("%lf\n", median);
      int cont1=0;
      int cont2=0;
      for (int x = 0; x < size-1; x++){
          if (pixels[x].L < median){
            pixeles_lado1[cont1] = pixels[x];
            cont1++;
          }
          else {
            pixeles_lado2[cont2] = pixels[x];
            cont2++;
          }
      }
```

The whole first part is a piece of code that goes through every pixel in an image and sees which color has the most range while adding each pixel s color to a list. Then i use those lists to sort the pixels by color strength. I then calculate the medium and put each pixel in one of two lists if it s color is above ore below the median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of `Color_lab` structs to the function `function()`, then you need to change the declaration for the `pixels_1[]` array. Right now you have declared this as an array of pointers to `Color_lab` structs. If you change this line to:

```
Color_lab pixels_1[size];
```

and then change the assignment to:

```
pixels_1[cont1] = pixels[x];
```

your type errors will go away.

I think that there are other problems here. For one, I don't see that the recursion converges on a base case, and so it looks like it will never end. For another, the variable `cont1` is incremented from 0 a total of `(finish - start)` times, so that you have:

```
pixels_1[0] = pixels[start];
...
pixels_1[finish - start - 1] = pixels[finish - 1];
```

which has walked off the end of the declared array:

```
size = floor(finish - start) / 2 + 1;
Color_lab pixels_1[size];
```

I imagine the segfault you are seeing is because of this.

I am not sure what the purpose of this function is (you might try giving it a more descriptive name), but it seems to be building an array of `Color_lab` structs. If you want to use this new array, you are probably going to have to find a way to pass it back out of the function. So you probably need to `malloc()` some space for this in the function, or pass in a statically declared array to receive the new elements.

Comment: Actually i had already tried that (and I just did again), but i get a segmentation fault. And one question, if i make that change, will i be able to use pixels_1 for the recursion? Because i d be using another type than the args type in function.

Comment: When you pass `pixels_1` to the function, this reference decays to a pointer to the first element of the array `pixels_1[]`, so you are passing a `Color_lab *` type, as called for in your function prototype. So yes, technically you can use `pixels_1` for the recursion if you have declared it to be an array of `Color_lab` structs, but there are other issues. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, as you can see above i ve implemented what you said but it is still not working, i m sure the error is in the pixels_1[cont1] = pixels[x] part because i take it out and the code runs perfectly, thanks again. If you think it will help I can add the rest of the code too.

Comment: How is the code failing? I do see that the original intent seemed to be to assign the values from `pixels[start] ` -- `pixels[start+size-1]` to the locations `pixels_1[0]` -- `pixels_1[size-1]`, where now you are assigning `pixels[0]` -- `pixels[size-2]` to the locations `pixels_1[0]` -- `pixels_1[size-2]`. I am not sure if this is responsible for your problem.

Comment: OK now I hope my edit is more useful, I posted the whole code and explained it below. The segmentation fault happens in pixel_1[x] -- pixel[x]

Comment: What are these two lines: `Color_lab pixeles_lado1[lol];` `Color_lab pixeles_lado2[lol];`? I don't see where `lol` is defined.

Comment: `pixeles_lado1[cont1] = pixels[x];` is a valid assignment, so long as the indices are not out of bounds. If you are having a segfault here, it is because either `cont1` or `x` has gone out of bounds. You should look at your program in a debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: lol is size, i changed it to make understandable but missed that. And i don t think it s out of bounds because the seg fault happens even when I try with pixeles_lado1[0] = pixels[0]

Comment: OK, I noticed something.... Your new code is missing some closing braces, and the recursive function call: I presume that you have them in your code and that they just did not make it into the code snippet that you posted. But, based on the original code that you posted, I am supposing that your recursive call looks something like: `palletear(pixels_1 , k-1, pater, inicio, fin/2, first, side);` You use the quantity `fin - inicio` in several places to declare arrays.

Comment: But, after several recursive calls the value of `fin` in the new frames will be less than the value of `inicio`, giving a negative value for `fin - inicio`, and meaning that you are declaring several arrays of negative size. This is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: First of all thaks for the patience, second, I am still not recursing, that is why it can t be a recursvie error. For now I m just trying to make the code work before starting the recursion (and you are right about the missing braces). I used valgrind to check on the code and it says invalid write of size 8, on the   `lum[x] = pixels[x].L;`   which is weird because it only crashes later. I presume this error means the size for my array isn t the right one, I just can t figure out why, since it is a double and I state it for the array that it will have doubles inside it.

Comment: Check your `quickSort()` function. I closed the remaining braces of your code, defined a dummy array of 100 `Color_lab` structs which I initialized to `.L = 1.0`, defined a `struct kd_node *pkd = NULL`, and called your function from `main()` like this: `palletear(pclab, 100, pkd, 0, 100, 0, 0);`. I added a  `printf("pixeles_lado1[%d].L = %lf\n",
                           cont1, pixeles_lado1[cont1].L);` after the assignment to `pixeles_lado1[cont1]`. After compiling, your `printf()` output `1.500000`, and mine output `pixeles_lado[0].L = 1.000000 ... pixeles_lado[99].L = 1.000000`.

Comment: I ran out of space to add that I commented out your call to `quickSort()` before compiling and running the test code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! the problem was in memory malloc, for some reason (actually no one figured out why), the array wasn t being properly formed as it was and by malloc I was able to not go out of bounds.